# JMeter - Use jar output for URL to load test

Tags: java, jmeter

I would like to use JMeter to test a Java service. However the URL I want to test has to be dynamically generated (timestamps, payload hash, etc). I created a self executable jar that outputs a valid URL.

```
java -jar file.jar

http://www.example.com/api?params=...
```

The URL changes each iteration. Is there a way I can configure JMeter to run the Jar to get the URL for each HTTP request it makes? Thanks!

Comment: I ended outputting the data I needed to CSV and used that as a data source to JMeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use combination of the following:

1. [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) (to spawn your utility JAR)
2. [Regular Expression Extractor](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm) (to get generated URL)

Details:

Given you have java binary in your system path you need the following:

Under Thread Group add an OS Process Sampler

- Set Command to be **java** (to be completely sure type full path to your java binary, i.e. "d:\apps\java6\bin\java.exe")
- Under Command Parameters add following: **-jar** **your.jar** EACH ON SEPARATE LINE, again it's better to use full path to your jar.
- Add View Results Tree listener at the same level as OS Process Sampler

If you run your Thead Group you should see the following:

System Call Complete.
Process Output:
http://example.com/api?params=....

I believe that you're interested in something, which comes after "params="

So get this value add a Regular Expression Extractor Post Processor as a child of OS Process sampler with following details:

- Reference name - any meaningful name for variable, let it be "params"
- Regular Expression - http://www.example.com/(.*)
- Template - $1$

That will extract api?params=... so you'll be able to use it as path for your HTTP Request as ${params}

Answer (score 0):

To run jar file in JMeter, place your JAR file and all the dependent to {JMeter_HOME}/lib/ext folder. Add a [BeanShell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) to your thread group to call methods from your Java class.

Answer (score 0):

Your jar need not be in the lib/ext folder of JMeter. Works for me in any directory