# jmeter run automation scripts from .jar file

Tags: java, maven, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have my functional automation scripts written in cucumber-java. I did below steps

1. Converted cucumber-java automation scripts to .jar file
2. jar file can be executed independently using cmd "java - jar XXX.jar --glue classpath:com/framework classpath:features"

now i want to include this jar file in jmeter and perform the load test, can you guys provide me steps to do this task

note : i copied jar file to /lib/ext folder but when i open jmeter i am getting below error

'An error occurred: Cannot inherit from final class'

i went and looked back in my code i dont have any class with final

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543642/jmeter-use-jar-output-for-url-to-load-test

Comment: i tried the same method and still facing issue 'An error occurred: Cannot inherit from final class'